# variable beforeskip in \@startsection

Tags: spacing, sectioning

Is it possible to have a "calculated" \beforeskip in `\@startsection` ?

I want the beforeskip of a subsection to be `1.5ex` unless the previous paragraph is a section. In that case I want the section and subsection to be separated by `1ex`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  of course this is "possible", but it's likely you would have to give up the default method of defining the format of a `\section`, and also of `\subsection` and perhaps lower levels to set switches indicating exactly where you are.  how this is done depends on what document class you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use (expandable) tests in the beforeskip-argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\iflarge
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {\iflarge -6cm \else -3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex\fi}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
abc
\section{First section}

\largetrue
abc
\section{Second section}
\end{document}
```

But from your description it is not clear if it is possible (and how) to test for your conditions.